# render angular component with dynamic styles and template

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, bootstrap-modal

I want to create an Angular component but I want to add the html and css dynamically. Is there a way when you create the component/modal to pass in the styles and html before rendering?

So basically I want to pass in the styles array and the template before doing the rendering below.

```
  @Component({
      styles: [],
      template: "",
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
    })
```

I create the component as a modal like this:

```
    const modal = this.modalService.open(SelectSelectorComponent, { size: 'xl' });
    modal.componentInstance.restaurantHtml = this.currentHtml;
    modal.result.then((selector: string) => {
        this.mealForm.setValue({mealSelector: selector})
    }, () => {
    });
```

Could I pass those variables into the componentInstance or something?
I want to do this because I don't want the modal to be affected of my global styles.

Comment: the requirement is doable, but with a huge pain and performance loss on the application (not exactly like described in the question, but still the same effect). could you describe your use case, where you need it. I believe you will get is a better solution for that use case

Comment: hmm okej. So basically i want the user to enter a url to a website and then i load the website in a modal and the user then picks different parts of the website that i want to scrape every day for information. So when they click an element i save a selector to pick the text inside of that element. does that help @andrei